# Why does the termination of custom objects look namely this way "__c"?

Tags: custom-object

What does this termination of custom objects mean?

Why does it have exactly two underscores?

And why is the special termination needed at all?

Comment: Love this question! Which begs the next one: why Obj__c instead of c__Obj :-)

Answer (score 9):

`__c` = custom Object

`__r` = custom Relationship

They are needed to distinguish between standard objects and custom object. This allows the user to have objects and fields with the same base name as standard objects and fields.

the double underscore is a standard way of terminating the name and is likely not to be in any other context so it works well. You cannot have a double underscore anywhere else in the name.

Naming Conventions......

Comment: And let's not forget __Share, __Tag, __History, etc based on the settings of the object.

Answer (score 6):

The reasons I've been told are three-fold:

1)  If, for some reason, a user wants to create a new object with the same name as an existing object (say Account) there has to be a systematic way to differentiate the two, without user-interaction.  Double-underscore is as good a way as any to standardize with a non-letter/number character that will likely not be duplicated.  In addition, it is a character string that is accepted by most (if not all) external systems.

2)  We live in a multi-tenant environment.  As such, SFDC needs to be able to easily identify objects, fields, etc within Orgs as being custom or standard from their end.  Standardziation across all environments is necessary to keep the lights on at the source.

3)  Since the relationships are also standardized with a similar nomenclature (double-underscore 'r') for similar reasons, and that nomenclature is not something that can be modified, it makes for easy understanding of the API.